# How can I make this Javascript validation apply to multiple numeric fields?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which works on a single field [NOTE: I found it online]. It is checking to see if the user presses a non-numeric key and then shows them the error message. Here's the code:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8);
    function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret; 
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<td align="right"><label for="field_1">Field 1</label></td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" 
        ondrop=return false;" 
        onpaste="return false;" name="field_1" maxlength="15" 
        value="<?php echo stripslashes($row["field_1"]) ?>" />
    <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none; font-weight: bold;">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
</td>
```

How do I change the Javascript (or HTML input) to allow me to apply this script to multiple fields?

Comment: Can you share a Fiddle / CodeSandbox / Stackblitz link for this?

Comment: https://js-enjttp.stackblitz.io [I've never used this service]

Comment: StackBlitz gives me this error when I enter anything in the field: `IsNumeric is not defined` <sigh>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsNumeric` function assigns error message to the `DOM Element` with `id` error.
In order to achieve the same solution for multiple fields, you will have to update the `isNumeric` function in the following way:

```
function IsNumeric(e, index) {
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  var ret =
    (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1;

    // attach error message to the field where the error is evaluated based on the index.
    document.getElementById("error-"+index).style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
  return ret;
}
```

And your HTML Code with multiple fields will look something like the following:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" tabindex=3><label for="field_1">Field 1</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event,1);" ondrop=return false;" onpaste="return false;" name="field_1" maxlength="15" value="" />
            <span id="error-1" style="color: Red; display: none; font-weight: bold;">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td align="right" tabindex=3><label for="field_2">Field 2</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event,2);" ondrop=return false;" onpaste="return false;" name="field_2" maxlength="15" value="" />
            <span id="error-2" style="color: Red; display: none; font-weight: bold;">Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Here is the stackblitz link to my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pgd2cl?file=index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `Input` listener on each Input like this:

```js
const IsNumeric = (e,index) => {
   let errorSpan=document.getElementById(`error${index+1}`);
   errorSpan.style.display = isNaN(e.target.value) ? 'inline' : 'none'
}; 

let numInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('numIn');

Object.values(numInputs).forEach((numIn,index)=>{
    numIn.addEventListener('input', (e)=>IsNumeric(e,index));
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td align="right">
     <label for="field_1">Field 1</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input
      class="numIn"
      type="text"
      id="text1"
      name="field_1"
      maxlength="15" 
      value=""
    />
    <span
      id="error1"
      style="color: Red; display: none; font-weight: bold;"
    >
      Input digits (0 - 9)
    </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="right">
     <label for="field_1">Field 2</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input
      class="numIn"
      type="text"
      id="text2"
      name="field_2"
      maxlength="15" 
      value=""
    />
    <span
      id="error2"
      style="color: Red; display: none; font-weight: bold;"
    >
      Input digits (0 - 9)
    </span>
  </td>
 <tr/>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove listeners in situations which need to remove.

Comment: The issue that I have with your code is that the numeric fields are not together on the form. One is at the top, a few in the middle, and one or two toward the bottom. I'd like to have the `span` error show next to the field to which it applies.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas Actually, You must add those yourself, But i'll update the answer to cover that.

Comment: Don't use html ```Table``` to create a form. It is not performant. You can use styled ```div```s or styled ```dl dt```.